# Deciding between Tasklet and Chunk based approach of Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I am newbie to Spring Batch and I have below requirement to implement using Spring Batch.

1. Read multiple REST API to get the desired data. The Desired data is divided into two sets say X (List) and Y(List)
2. Process both set of data to do some calculation for each object of the List
3. Write two XML files and send email with attaching both the XMLs files.

Could anyone please suggest which approach is best suited for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The first question to help you in that decision is the following: what is (or what can be considered as) an "item" in your case? What is the entity that represents a single unit of aggregate data in your domain model?

Once you are able to define what an item is, you can easily proceed with the design of your chunk-oriented step. Please note that you might need more than one chunk-oriented step (probably in combination with simple tasklets) to implement the requirement. The idea of using staging tables is a good option to materialize intermediate state between steps, but that only works with small/medium data sets.